# How to produce static references from append-only arena?

Tags: rust

In my application (a compiler), I'd like to create data cyclic data structures of various kinds throughout my program's execution that all have the same lifetime (in my case, lasting until the end of compilation). In addition,

- I don't need to worry about multi-threading
- I only need to append information - no need to delete or garbage collect
- I only need immutable references to my data

This seemed like a good use case for an Arena, but I saw that this would require passing the arena around to every function in my program, which seemed like a large overhead.

So instead I found a macro called `thread_local!` that I can use to define global data. Using this, I thought I might be able to define a custom type that wraps an index into the array, and implement `Deref` on that type:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

enum Floop {
    CaseA,
    CaseB,
    CaseC(FloopRef),
    CaseD(FloopRef),
    CaseE(Vec<FloopRef>),
}

thread_local! {
    static FLOOP_ARRAY: RefCell<Vec<Box<Floop>>> = RefCell::new(Vec::new());
}

pub struct FloopRef(usize);

impl std::ops::Deref for FloopRef {
    type Target = Floop;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        return FLOOP_ARRAY.with(|floops| &floops.borrow()[self.0]);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    // initialize some data
    FLOOP_ARRAY.with(|floops| {
        floops.borrow_mut().push(Box::new(Floop::CaseA));
        let idx = floops.borrow_mut().len();
        floops.borrow_mut().push(Box::new(Floop::CaseC(FloopRef(idx))));
    });
}
```

Unfortunately I run into lifetime errors:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:36
   |
20 |         return FLOOP_ARRAY.with(|floops| &floops.borrow()[self.0]);
   |                                  ------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                                  |     |
   |                                  |     return type of closure is &'2 Box<Floop>
   |                                  has type `&'1 RefCell<Vec<Box<Floop>>>`

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:20:36
   |
20 |         return FLOOP_ARRAY.with(|floops| &floops.borrow()[self.0]);
   |                                          ^---------------^^^^^^^^
   |                                          ||
   |                                          |temporary value created here
   |                                          returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

What I'd like to tell the compiler is that I promise I'm never going to remove entries from the Array and that I'm not going to share values across threads and that the array will last until the end of the program so that I can in essence just return a `&'static` reference to a `Floop` object. But Rust doesn't seem to be convinced this is safe.

Is there any kind of Rust helper library that would let me do something like this? Or are there safety holes even when I guarantee I only append / only use data with a single thread?

Comment: thread local are not at all what you want, I advice you to use KISS.

Comment: If you do not need to drop, maybe you can just leak?

Comment: As a fun exercise, I decided to implement a thread-safe arena. See https://users.rust-lang.org/t/code-review-for-thread-safe-arena-implementation/87416.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have a reference, you could send the data to another thread, then watch it after it has been dropped because the creating thread was finished.

Even if you would solve this problem, this would still require `unsafe` code, as the compiler can't be convinced that growing the `Vec` won't invalidate existing references. This is true in this case since you're using `Box`, but the compiler cannot know that.

If you pinky promise to never touch the data after the creating thread has finished, you can use the following code. Note that this code is technically UB as when the `Vec` will grow, we will move all `Box`es, and at least currently, [moving a `Box` invalidates all references deriven from it](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326):

```rust
enum Floop {
    CaseA,
    CaseB,
    CaseC(&'static Floop),
    CaseD(&'static Floop),
    CaseE(Vec<&'static Floop>),
}

thread_local! {
    static FLOOP_ARRAY: RefCell<Vec<Box<Floop>>> = RefCell::new(Vec::new());
}

fn alloc_floop(floop: Floop) -> &'static mut Floop {
    FLOOP_ARRAY.with(|floops| {
        let mut floops = floops.borrow_mut();
        floops.push(Box::new(floop));
        let floop = &mut **floops.last_mut().unwrap() as *mut Floop;
        // SAFETY: We never access the data after it has been dropped, and we are
        // the only who access this `Box` as we access a `Box` only immediately
        // after pushing it.
        unsafe { &mut *floop }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let floop_a = alloc_floop(Floop::CaseA);
    let floop_b = alloc_floop(Floop::CaseC(floop_a));
}
```

A better solution would be something like a thread-safe arena that you can use in a `static`, but sadly, I found no crate that implements that.

Comment: Huge thanks! @Chayin Friedman When you say "moving a Box invalidates all references deriven from it" are you describing basically a theoretical concern? I assumed Box, String, and other types listed in StableDeref as an example should have stable addresses as long as we don't call drop: https://docs.rs/stable_deref_trait/latest/stable_deref_trait/trait.StableDeref.html. (Also I'm compiling to WebAssembly so if this guarantee is related to LLVM output, it might not matter to me, but still curious.)

Comment: @ChristopherRybicki Your assumption were wrong, that is what I'm trying to say. It is undefined behavior as currently defined, which means that everything can happen (which is the reason `stable_deref` is unsound, not by itself, but it doesn't fill its purpose). We even give LLVM's `noalias` to `Box`, meaning actual miscomplations may happen (although I haven't seen one yet, but this is not a good argument for UB). About `Vec` (and `String` derived from it), although it is also mentioned in the linked issue, the consensus re them appears to be that they don't invalidate references when moving.